# Using backslashes in string resource in Android

Tags: android, string

What is the proper way to use backslashes in a string resource in Android?

If, for example I want this exact string to be sent in a POST request from a string resource:

```
"something\\somethingelse"
```

Is the following xml correct then:

```
<string name="something">something\\somethingelse</string>
```

It is writing out the correct string in my tests, but I can't help but thinking that some devices may escape one of the backslashes and write out:

```
"something\somethingelse"
```

instead.

So how should this be written to make sure all devices get the same string with both backslashes?

Comment: Try using Unicode of backslash `\u005c`

Comment: Thanks! I can't test it though.. I just need a solution to make sure it doesn't ecape one of the backslashes. So does this ensure that both backslashes will be written out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is java, it will be escaped automatically.
You can easily do 4 backslashes to avoid that

```
<string name="something">something\\\\somethingelse</string>
```

You actually don't need to use any unicode or encoded string

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In my particular case, I am sending the string in a POST request. I monitored the traffic, using proxy software (Charles) and can confirm that the string resoruce "<string name="something">something\\somethingelse</string>", sends "something\\somethingelse". This does not comply with what you are saying.

Comment: That is weird... Did you use Context.getString(R.string.id);? If so, maybe something wrong with your request when you setting the parameter, because it will not change your string.

Comment: It's very weird. Yes i am using Context.getString(R.string.id). Can't figure out why it behaves like this. the request should be fine. It's a very simple POST request

Comment: Maybe if you share the code for your POST request, we can figured it out.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. I got it working. My problem was something else, but this is still the correct answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
<string name="something" formatted="false">something\\somethingelse</string>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't test it though.. I just need a solution to make sure it doesn't ecape one of the backslashes. So does this ensure that both backslashes will be written out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following encoded string for backslash ("`&#92;`")

```
<string name="something" formatted="false">something&#92;somethingelse</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this string

```
<string name="something">"something/\/\somethingelse"</string>
```

in place of

```
<string name="something">something\\somethingelse</string>
```

Also you can test it using this string in your xml

```
android:text="@string/something"
```